# while loop - Sql Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, while-loop

**Input**

```
 date        |  username |    program | workflow  | Pending_Audits  |Audits_Carry_Forward

 31-07-2018  |  ram      |   Pre pay  | Sisi      |      -1         |      -12 
 27-07-2018  |  ram      |   Pre pay  | Sisi      |      -111       |       0
 25-07-2018  |  ram      |   Pre pay  | Sisi      |      -16        |     -14
```

I have the above table I'm writing a while condition to update the Audits_Carry_Forward column from the given date.

The logic is to update the given date's audits_carry_forward into the next row pending_audits column which has the same program and workflow with respect to the given date

**Desired Output:**

```
 date        |  username |    program | workflow  | Pending_Audits  |Audits_Carry_Forward

 31-07-2018  |  ram      |   Pre pay  | Sisi      |      -1         |      -111 
 27-07-2018  |  ram      |   Pre pay  | Sisi      |      -111       |      -16
 25-07-2018  |  ram      |   Pre pay  | Sisi      |      -16        |      -14
```

so in this case i want to update the Pending_audits data of '25-07-2018' to the audits_carry_forward that are above the given date.

The sql Logic I tried

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2018-07-25' 
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(100)= 'ram' 
DECLARE @program VARCHAR(100)= 'Pre pay' 
DECLARE @workflow VARCHAR(100)= 'Sisi' 
DECLARE @a INT 

WHILE ( @date <= Cast(Getdate() AS DATE) ) 
  BEGIN 
      SET @a = (SELECT Count(*) 
                FROM   dbo.homehealthpp1 
                WHERE  username = @username 
                       AND program = @program 
                       AND workflow = @workflow 
                       AND date = @date) 

      IF ( @a = 1 ) 
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE dbo.homehealthpp1 
            SET    audits_carry_forward = (SELECT pending_audits 
                                           FROM   dbo.homehealthpp1 
                                           WHERE  username = @username 
                                                  AND program = @program 
                                                  AND workflow = @workflow 
                                                  AND date = @date) 
            WHERE  username = @username 
                   AND program = @program 
                   AND workflow = @workflow 
                   AND date = Cast(Dateadd(d, 1, @date) AS DATE) 
        END 

      SET @date = Cast(Dateadd(d, 1, @date) AS DATE) 
  END
```

The above case works when the date is sequentially present. but it doesn't work for the scenarios where the date is not sequential like the above case.

Comment: I don't get it.  I get how the two most recent dates are updated, but not 2018-07-25.

Comment: @GordonLinoff With respect to '2018-07-25' that is an inserted data.  From that data i want to update the next recent date data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `username/workflow/program` are the common value, you can do this.

We add a `row_number()` partitioned on the `username/workflow/program` then we can update the `audits_carry_forward` value for a matched `username/workflow/program` from the row below (`rn`) in the set (-1), but only when the row (`rn`) is not 1.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE ([date] DATE, username VARCHAR(100), program VARCHAR(10), workflow VARCHAR(10), pending_audits INT, audits_carry_forward INT)

INSERT INTO @Test
VALUES ('2018-07-31','ram','Pre pay','Sisi',-1,-12),
       ('2018-07-27','ram','Pre pay','Sisi',-111,0),
       ('2018-07-25','ram','Pre pay','Sisi',-16,-14)

;WITH x AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY username,program,workflow ORDER BY [date]) AS RN
    FROM @Test
)

UPDATE T1 SET audits_carry_forward = (SELECT pending_audits FROM X T2 WHERE T1.username=T2.username AND T1.program=T2.program AND T1.workflow=T2.workflow AND T2.RN=T1.RN-1)
FROM X T1
WHERE T1.RN!=1

SELECT *
FROM @Test
ORDER BY [date] DESC
```

It's worth noting the use of loops/cursors is not advisable in SQL.  This is called an RBAR (row by agonizing row) method, and is far more resource expensive than a set-based approach whereas all data is updated simultaneously.  You will find with time and experience that most (albeit not all) things can be done without using loops/cursors.